# How can I list all recent jobs for a GitLab Runner?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm interested in listing all the jobs that has run on a GitLab Runner for a specific period (the last six months in my case). Or to be more precise: I want to find all *projects* that has had a job run. Is there a way to do this, either through the web interface or by logging into the runner?

In the web interface I've tried looking in Admin Area > Runners > [Select_specific_runner]. Here I can see "Recent jobs served by this Runner", but this only lists the last 30 runs.

I've also tried experimenting with the `gitlab-runner` command from the command line, but I haven't found a way to list actual runs.

Comment: Any news on how to list curent running jobs ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt there is a UI page for that now.
Funny enough it was possible a couple of major versions ago - to see jobs done by a runner on its page.

But most certainly you can do that via GitLab API:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/jobs.html

It could be even simpler if using API client, say this one for Python: https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api-usage.html

Comment: Thanks. I ended up extracting all the jobs from the API, and then I'll parse/filter those as needed.